# The Standard Way To Encode/Decode To/From Binary Object In C++

Tags: c++, encode

I want to encode/decode some basic type into/from binary.

The test code may looks like this.

```
 int main()
{
    int iter = 0;
    char* binary = new char[100];

    int32_t version = 1;
    memcpy(binary, &version, sizeof(int32_t));
    iter+=sizeof(int32_t);

    const char* value1 = "myvalue";
    memcpy(binary+iter, value1, strlen(value1));
    iter+=strlen(value1);

    double value2 = 0.1;
    memcpy(binary+iter, &value2, sizeof(double));
#warning TODO - big/small endian - fixed type length

    return 0;
}
```

But I still need to solve a lot of problems, such as the endian and fixed type length.

So I want to know if there is a standard way to implement this.

Simultaneously, I don't want to use any third-party implementation, such as Boost and so on. Because I need to keep my code simple and Independent.

If there is a function/class like `NSCoding` in `Objc`, it will be best. I wonder if there is same thing in C++ standard library.

Comment: A standard way doesn't exist for such an high level feature, reinventing the wheel doesn't look like a good design IMHO, just stick to one of the many libraries to manage this such as [flatbuffers](https://google.github.io/flatbuffers/) or [protobuf](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/)

Comment: You can not keep your code simple and independent in C++ if you take attention on things like endian, type length, padding and so on.

Comment: I would advice to use FlatBuffers library. It will generete cross-platform code for serialization/deserialization of your data for any language you want from wide range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most standard thing you have in every OS base library is ntohs/ntohl and htons/htonl that you can use to go from 'host' to 'network' byte order that is considered the standard for serializing integers.

The problem is that there is not yet a standard API for 64bit types and you should anyway serialize strings by yourself (the most common method is to prepend string data with an int16/32 containing the string length in bytes).

Again C/C++ do not offer a standard way to serialize data from/to a binary buffer or an XML or a JSON, but there are tons of libraries that implement this, for example, one of the most used, also if it comes with a lot of dependencies is:

[Boost serialize](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/libs/serialization/doc/)

Other libraries widely used but that require a precompilation step are:

[Google procol buffers](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/)

[FlatBuffers](https://google.github.io/flatbuffers/flatbuffers_guide_tutorial.html)

Answer (score 3):

No, there are no serialization functions within the standard library. Use a library or implement it by yourself.

Note that raw new and delete is a bad practice in C++.

Comment: What do you mean with 'raw new and delete is a bad practice in C++' ?

Comment: @Bob__ It's very hasty code to show what I mean only. I wouldn't write this kind of code in my project. Usually, I would use `std::shared_ptr`.

Comment: std::shared_ptr is actually rarely used. Mostly you want a std::unique_ptr without any additional overhead, or an appropriate container.